# Counter loop on pressure sensors arduino

Tags: arduino, counter

I'm using four fsr pressure sensors in parallel connection to each other. Below are the coding for my project.

I have a problem with the counter values where it display four added counter values for each of the sensor.

I need to get a counter values where it is added each time pressure is detected and if there is no pressure anymore, it will remain the previous counter value.

```js
int fsrPin[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};    
int fsrReading;     
int fsrVoltage;     

unsigned long fsrResistance;  
unsigned long fsrConductance; 
long fsrForce;   
int pinCount = 4;
int counter = 0;

 
void setup(void) {
  for(int thisPin = 0; thisPin < pinCount; thisPin++) {
    pinMode(fsrPin[thisPin], OUTPUT);
  }
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
 
void loop(void) {
  
  for(int thisPin = 0; thisPin < pinCount; thisPin++) {
    fsrReading = analogRead(fsrPin[thisPin]);
    Serial.print("Analog reading ");
    Serial.print(fsrPin[thisPin]); 
    Serial.print("=> ");
    Serial.println(fsrReading);
    fsrVoltage = map(fsrReading, 0, 1023, 0, 5000);
    Serial.print("Voltage reading in mV = ");
    Serial.println(fsrVoltage);
    
  if (fsrVoltage == 0) {
    Serial.println("No pressure");  
  } else {
    // The voltage = Vcc * R / (R + FSR) where R = 10K and Vcc = 5V
    // so FSR = ((Vcc - V) * R) / V
    fsrResistance = 5000 - fsrVoltage;     
    fsrResistance *= 10000;                
    fsrResistance /= fsrVoltage;
    Serial.print("FSR resistance in ohms = ");
    Serial.println(fsrResistance);
 
    fsrConductance = 1000000;           
    fsrConductance /= fsrResistance;
    Serial.print("Conductance in microMhos: ");
    Serial.println(fsrConductance);
 
    if (fsrConductance <= 1000) {
      fsrForce = fsrConductance / 80;
      Serial.print("Force in Newtons: ");
      Serial.println(fsrForce);      
    } else {
      fsrForce = fsrConductance - 1000;
      fsrForce /= 30;
      Serial.print("Force in Newtons: ");
      Serial.println(fsrForce);            
    }
  }

  for(int thisPin=0; thisPin < pinCount; thisPin++){
  if (fsrForce != 0) {    
    counter++;
    Serial.print("Counter = ");
    Serial.println(counter);
  } else {
    counter;
    Serial.print("Counter = ");
    Serial.println(counter);
  }
  }
  Serial.println("--------------------");
  }
  delay(3000);
}
```

The actual problem is as below where I need to find a correct condition for looping the value of the counter:

```js
 for(int thisPin=0; thisPin < pinCount; thisPin++){
  if (fsrForce != 0) {    
    counter++;
    Serial.print("Counter = ");
    Serial.println(counter);
  } else {
    counter;
    Serial.print("Counter = ");
    Serial.println(counter);
  }
  }
```

[FOUR COUNTER VALUES IN EACH ANALOG READING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s799i.png)

Comment: So what does it do now? Do you just want to increment counter each time there is some pressure on any of the 4 sensors? Would adding `fsrForce = 0` after `if (fsrVoltage == 0) {` help?

Comment: It display four counter values on each sensor readings. Yes exactly. I want the counter to increases as long as there is pressure on the sensors.

Comment: What is it doing now? Is it just displaying `Counter = 0` all the time?

Comment: When there is no pressure it displays

Comment: When there is no pressure it displays `Counter=0` 4 times for each sensor reading but when pressure exists at the first sensor, it shows `Counter=1` `Counter=2` `Counter=3` `Counter=4` for one reading. And for another 3 readings the values keep increasing even though there is no pressure on it. For a more clear explaination, I've attached the picture(FOUR COUNTER VALUES IN EACH ANALOG READING) in above question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main problem is that you are checking if `fsrForce != 0`, However fsrForce does not really have a chance to get to zero because it's dependent on fsrVoltage and is set only if fsrVoltage is positive.

Just set `fsrForce = 0` when `fsrVoltage < VOLTAGE_THRESHOLD` and you should get the expected behavior.

Try this:

```
int fsrPin[] = {
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3
};
int fsrReading;
int fsrVoltage;

unsigned long fsrResistance;
unsigned long fsrConductance;
long fsrForce;
int pinCount = 4;
int counter = 0;

// add threshold
const float VOLTAGE_THRESHOLD = 0.2;

void setup(void) {
    for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < pinCount; thisPin++) {
        pinMode(fsrPin[thisPin], OUTPUT);
    }
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(void) {

    for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < pinCount; thisPin++) {
        fsrReading = analogRead(fsrPin[thisPin]);
        Serial.print("Analog reading ");
        Serial.print(fsrPin[thisPin]);
        Serial.print("=> ");
        Serial.println(fsrReading);
        fsrVoltage = map(fsrReading, 0, 1023, 0, 5000);
        Serial.print("Voltage reading in mV = ");
        Serial.println(fsrVoltage);

        if (fsrVoltage < VOLTAGE_THRESHOLD) {

            // reset the fsrForce when there is no pressure
            fsrForce = 0

            Serial.println("No pressure");
        } else {
            // The voltage = Vcc * R / (R + FSR) where R = 10K and Vcc = 5V
            // so FSR = ((Vcc - V) * R) / V
            fsrResistance = 5000 - fsrVoltage;
            fsrResistance *= 10000;
            fsrResistance /= fsrVoltage;
            Serial.print("FSR resistance in ohms = ");
            Serial.println(fsrResistance);

            fsrConductance = 1000000;
            fsrConductance /= fsrResistance;
            Serial.print("Conductance in microMhos: ");
            Serial.println(fsrConductance);

            if (fsrConductance <= 1000) {
                fsrForce = fsrConductance / 80;
                Serial.print("Force in Newtons: ");
                Serial.println(fsrForce);
            } else {
                fsrForce = fsrConductance - 1000;
                fsrForce /= 30;
                Serial.print("Force in Newtons: ");
                Serial.println(fsrForce);
            }
        }

        for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < pinCount; thisPin++) {
            if (fsrForce != 0) {
                counter++;
            }
            Serial.print("Counter = ");
            Serial.println(counter);
        }
        Serial.println("--------------------");
    }
    delay(3000);
}
```

Comment: Tried it and it is not working as I need :( It still add up the values of the previous counters

Comment: Do you want to have a counter for each of the sensors? Now its just adds 1 to the counter each cycle that the reading is non-zero.